# Post Mapping annotation not working on springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

guys I am sorry for asking stupid question.
But I am a student and code doesnt work properly

When i make post request it doesnt work only get requests are working

```
   @PostMapping("/print")

       public ResponseEntity<?> print()
   {
       return ResponseEntity.ok("Успешно изтрихте записа!");
   }


     @PostMapping("/save")
     public ResponseEntity<?> saveOrUpdate(@RequestBody userRequest form){

          City city = cityRepository.findById(form.getCityId()).orElse(cityRepository.findById(17L).get());
         boolean isNew = form.getId() == null;
         Users users = new Users (
                 form.getId(),
                 form.getName(),
                 form.getNum(),
//              cityId == null? cityRepository.save(new City(cityName)): cityRepository.findById(cityId).orElse(null) );
                 city );
         users = userRepository.save(users);
         Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
         response.put("generatedId", users.getId());
         if(isNew) {
             response.put("message", "Успешно записан!");
         }
         else{
             response.put("message", "Успешно редактиран!");
         }

         return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
     }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your issue? Do you have debugging details?

Comment: How are you making a POST request? Which tool do you use?

Comment: Is there any error, that is thrown? Do you get a Status Code? For the PostMapping you created, you will need to provide the Request with a Body, which contains a `userRequest`. What does this userRequest look like and what does the class say, what it should look like?

Comment: How is the class annotated?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what's the cause is but, this could be CSRF related issue. To make sure, try disabling CSRF in spring security configurations.
But, in the long run, you need to provide the CSRF token.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApiSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not clear with the issue so its hard to debug but I think the problem could be in the view page, so try adding this method="post" in from your form tag like this

```
<form action="/print" method="post">
```

and if you don't want to do this, change this @PostMapping to @RequestMapping.